# Combine two different queries into one and paginate the query - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Basically, I want to show the items that have the tag "Featured" first, then show all the items that do not have the tag "Featured, and then paginate the results.

```
$featured = array(
'post_type' => 'aircraft-refueling',
'tag' => 'featured'
);
$not_featured = array(
'post_type' => 'aircraft-refueling',
'tag__not_in' => array('592')
);
```

Here is the pagination:

```
function pagination()
{
global $wp_query;
$big = 999999999;
echo paginate_links(array(
    'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
));
}
```

I am not too familiar with PHP, but I am guessing that I need to merge the queries into a new query and then paginate that new query? Help is highly appreciated! If there is a better method, please advise as well.

EDIT: Here is my progress. I almost got it to work but I am getting an error with this code even though it looks fine to me...?

```
<?php 
$featured = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'aircraft-refueling',
    'tag' => 'featured'
    ));
$notfeatured = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'aircraft-refueling',
    'tag__not_in' => array('592')
    ));
$mergedposts = array_merge( $featured, $notfeatured );

$postids = array();
foreach( $mergedposts as $item ) {
$postids[]=$item->ID;
}
$uniqueposts = array_unique($postids);

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post__in' => $uniqueposts,
    'post_type' => 'aircraft-refueling',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    ));
foreach( $posts as $post ) :
setup_postdata($post);
?>
```

Then the standard query:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
// THE CONTENT
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the provided code above I can't figure how you run the loop which display data.
If you did:

```php
  <?php foreach( $posts as $post ) : 
     setup_postdata( $post ); 
  endforeach; ?>
```

then there is no need from second loop:

```php
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  // THE CONTENT
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

because `setup_postdata()` and `the_post()` did basically the same - they setup global `$post` object with data from the loop so template tags like `the_title()`, `the_ID()` ... can work properly.

So you must:

- If you use `query_posts()`

```php
  <?php foreach ( $posts as $post ):
     setup_postdata( $post ) 
     //THE CONTENT (the_title(), the_ID() will work 
  endforeach; ?>
```

- If you use `WP_Query()` (I think this is the best way)

```php
  <?php
  $posts = new WP_Query( array(
      'post__in' => $uniqueposts,
      'post_type' => 'aircraft-refueling',
      'post_status' => 'publish'
  ));

  if( $posts->have_posts() ):
      while( $posts->have_posts() ): $posts->the_post()
      //THE CONTENT (the_title(), the_ID() will work 
      endwhile; 
  endif;
  ?>
```

In both cases you must do `wp_reset_postdata()` after the loop.

**PS:**
In many cases if you do query with `custom_post_types` this will brake the pagination :)

If this is the case, check this link for ideas: [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/paginate-custom-post-types/)

And last: Do you need this `array_unique` check? The post will have or have not this tag...